# How to autoplay Video with sound like Twitch Website

Tags: javascript, html, web, video, autoplay

I'm trying to make video to autoplay with sound on page load, before any user interaction.
Found a lot of answering, but they all refer to the "[Chrome's Autoplay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#iframe)"
But why this [website](https://www.twitch.tv/mikecryptolife) can autoplay with sound without comply the aforementioned policy?(no iframe, no user interaction and not muted)

Comment: @Luke Thanks for your comment, it's helpful.